# What does it mean for a binary relation to be an order on "equivalence classes" under another binary relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I am a bit confused about this statement in "Introduction to Set Theory" by Hrbackek and Jech. The statement is as follows: "|A| <= |B| behaves like an ordering on the "equvivalence classes" under equvipotence". Equipotence is defined as a set A and B are equipotent iff there is a one-one function f with domain A and range B and is denoted by |A|=|B|

I would like to understand what does it mean for a binary relation R1 to be an ordering on A/R2 where R2 is a an equivalence relation in A and A/R2 is the set of all equivalence classes modulo R2.

Thanks

Comment: Well, first of all, note the word "like."

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this? As in what do you think the statement means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that if you consider the collection of equivalence classes, and this order defined $\leq$, then it is a partial order. Namely, reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive.

The problem is that usually, $|A|$ is not a set, and the collection of different equivalence classes is too big to be a set as well (even if we managed to choose a unique representative from each class). So it's not really a partial order. It's not even a partial order whose domain is a proper class, because as I wrote, the objects ordered by this order are themselves not sets but proper classes.

Comment: How is the order <= defined for equivalence classes?

Comment: Abdul, suppose that the equivalence classes were sets, and that there was only set many of them. Then $\leq$ was really a partial order. Right?

Comment: Suppose C1 = {A,B} and C2={C,D} be two equivalence classes mod equipotence relation. Then do you define <= between C1 and C2 as C1 <= C2 iff for all A belongs to C1 and all B belongs to C2 |A| <= |B|?

Comment: Yes. That's the general idea. Only that here we can't quite do it, because the equivalence classes are not sets, and there are too many of them to put them into a single collection. But we can still *say*, informally, that this is a partial order, even if it's only behaving like one, and not really one.